# Not reading resource property in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have bean trying to load the JKS file.

```
protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

private KeyStore keyStore;
private char[] keyStorePassword;
private KeyStore trustStore;
/**
 * @param keyStore the keyStore to set
 */
public void setKeyStore(Resource keyStore) {
    this.keyStore = getKeystoreFromResource(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
}
/**
 * @param trustStore the trustStore to set
 */
public void setTrustStore(Resource trustStore) {
    this.trustStore = getKeystoreFromResource(trustStore, keyStorePassword);
}
/**
 * @param keyStorePassword the keyStorePassword to set
 */
public void setKeyStorePassword(char[] keyStorePassword) {
    this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
}
/**
 * 
 * @param resource
 * @param password
 * @return
 */
protected static KeyStore getKeystoreFromResource(Resource resource, char[] password) {
    try {
        KeyStore k = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        k.load(resource.getInputStream(), password);
        return k;
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("failed to load keystore from " + resource.getDescription(), e);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("failed to load keystore from " + resource.getDescription(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("failed to load keystore from " + resource.getDescription(), e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("failed to load keystore from " + resource.getDescription(), e);
    }

}
```

and I have set the resource value as

```
    <property name="keyStore" value="${keyStore}"/>
```

in properties

```
   keyStore=/home/users/test.jks
```

But I am getting a file not found exception when I try to invoke the same.

I am not sure whether I am setting the resource value incorrectly.

Adam.

Comment: How do you load the properties file in Spring. I think you need a property placeholder declaration in your Spring context config.

Comment: prefix your property value with `file:`. So `file:/home/users/test.jks` in general a classpath based context is used to load files, which means that the default location to look for files (resources) is the classpath. Hence the `file:` prefix to tell Spring to load it from the file system instead.